# How to add ArrayList of ArrayList values into Arraylist?

Tags: java, android

I have a source list of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. I want to put all the strings from the source list into a destination list of type `ArrayList<String>`. How do I do this?

Example:

```
sourceList = { {"a","b"}, {"c","b"} }
destinationList = { "a","b","c","d" }
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can't get what you are asking?

Comment: Tell us what is your problem ... and also peace of code

Comment: @Vishali Neither can we

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for-each` and `addAll()`:

```
for (ArrayList<String> subList : listOfLists) {
    listofStrings.addAll(subList);
}
```

See: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: This is arraylist.you are adding arraylist values.i want arrayofarrayList

Comment: If I use arrayofarrayList I am getting only last index in my arraylist

Comment: @Vishali, you need to post some of your code so that we can help you. Please edit your question and include the relevant code.